# How to space two buttons

Tags: html

I am trying two put space between these two buttons

Tried `style="margin-right:` but it pushed the button down instead of keeping it even with the other button

```html
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-container">


  <div class="w3-show-inline-block">
  <div class="w3-bar">
    <p style="text-align: left;"><a class="global-btn" style="margin-top: 0;" href="https://queencitylocal.com/contact/">&gt;&gt;&gt;Click Here to get Started Now&lt;&lt;&lt;</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-show-inline-block">
  <div class="w3-bar">
    <p style="text-align: right;"><a class="global-btn" style="margin-top: 0;" href="https://queencitylocal.com/contact/">&gt;&gt;&gt;Schedule call and LEARN MORE &lt;&lt;&lt;</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add all relevant css-code to the question.

Comment: What would happen if you added a style="float:right;" to the div (i.e., w3-bar) you want in the right?

Answer (score 0):

You could use relative and absolute positioning to align the buttons to the left and right respectively, and use `w3-container` as the main element to base positioning on.

```html
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-container" style='width: 100%; position: relative;'>

  <div class="w3-show-inline-block" style="left: 0; position: absolute;">
  <div class="w3-bar">
    <p><a class="global-btn" href="https://queencitylocal.com/contact/">&gt;&gt;&gt;Click Here to get Started Now&lt;&lt;&lt;</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-show-inline-block" style="right: 0; position: absolute;">
  <div class="w3-bar">
    <p><a class="global-btn" href="https://queencitylocal.com/contact/">&gt;&gt;&gt;Schedule call and LEARN MORE &lt;&lt;&lt;</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Another option is to use [flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) if that's something you can support. In that case, you can insert an extra "spacer" element to take up as much space as its siblings will allow.

```html
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<body>

<div class="w3-container" style='width: 100%; display: flex;'>

  <div class="w3-show-inline-block" style="flex: 0; white-space: nowrap;">
  <div class="w3-bar">
    <p><a class="global-btn" href="https://queencitylocal.com/contact/">&gt;&gt;&gt;Click Here to get Started Now&lt;&lt;&lt;</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="spacer" style="flex: 1;"></div>

  <div class="w3-show-inline-block" style="flex: 0; white-space: nowrap;">
  <div class="w3-bar">
    <p><a class="global-btn" href="https://queencitylocal.com/contact/">&gt;&gt;&gt;Schedule call and LEARN MORE &lt;&lt;&lt;</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a Padding-Right so there is a space between the fields you want.

```
<html>
    <head>    
        <title>W3.CSS</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="w3-container">          
            <div class="w3-show-inline-block">
                <div class="w3-bar" style="padding-right: 200px;">
                    <p style="text-align: left;"><a class="global-btn" style="margin-top: 0;" href="https://queencitylocal.com/contact/">&gt;&gt;&gt;Click Here to get Started Now&lt;&lt;&lt;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-show-inline-block">
                <div class="w3-bar">
                    <p style="text-align: right;"><a class="global-btn" style="margin-top: 0;" href="https://queencitylocal.com/contact/">&gt;&gt;&gt;Schedule call and LEARN MORE &lt;&lt;&lt;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've copied your code (below), and modified it.

I've added colors to the (focus) divs to show the containers and where they are displayed on the screen.
The only real thing I've done is, added a float:right to the second div with class="w3-bar".

I've also added a width:900px to the w3-container div, to control the horizontal distance of the container on the screen. You can change the width to see the results.

Note: if you set it to 'auto', it will be governed by its parent's width.

```
<div class="w3-container" style="background-color: red;width:900px;">


  <div class="w3-show-inline-block" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <div class="w3-bar">
        <p style="text-align: left;"><a class="global-btn" style="margin-top: 0;" href="https://queencitylocal.com/contact/">&gt;&gt;&gt;Click Here to get Started Now&lt;&lt;&lt;</a></p>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w3-show-inline-block" style="background-color: green;float:right;">
      <div class="w3-bar">
        <p style="text-align: right;"><a class="global-btn" style="margin-top: 0;" href="https://queencitylocal.com/contact/">&gt;&gt;&gt;Schedule call and LEARN MORE &lt;&lt;&lt;</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```